# Stuck on launch screen Xcode7

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I just updated my xocde6 to xcode7 .When run code app stuck on launch screen.And showing a warning :-*"-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "kindle://home" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme kindle"*.I don't know what to do please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my os was Yosemite 10.10.5 when I change my os to EI Captain this issue is no more.